# Would rabbit mq be what I want for multiple requests (PHP)

Tags: php, laravel-5, rabbitmq, queue

So I have a console app written using laravel 5.5 and I have to make roughly 2400 GET Requests for articles from Helpscout which limits you to 2000 Requests per ten minutes or 600 seconds, and I currently use Guzzle to pool the requests and do 20 at a time.

I am curious if there is a way I could use Laravels Queue system, Rabbit Mq and say do 1900 of said requests and then wait the 600 seconds before finishing the last. essentially chunking the massive amount by x and doing y with in the thresh hold.

**I have contacted Helpscout and they said there was no way around the 2000 per 600 seconds**

So I am curious what solutions you guys might have that might alleviate me hitting their rate limit. I thought of using PHP's `sleep()` method but that seems wrong.

Would a queue system where I could then wait x seconds in between the "chunks" work? or am I over thinking this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a message queue for this.
I'd just use a job scheduler that is available in your environment to run your app every 10 minutes. Your app will do its 2000 requests and the shut itself down. For linux it can be [cron](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cron) or [systemd timers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers).